# Use class name in compile-time logging source generation

Tags: c#, .net

We're using [compile-time logging source generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logger-message-generator) with the `LoggerMessageAttribute`, e. g.:

```cs
public static partial class LoggerExtensions
{
    [LoggerMessage(
        EventId = 1953,
        EventName = "ExecutingQuery",
        Level = LogLevel.Information,
        Message = "Executing query {MyQuery}")]
    public static partial void ExecutingQuery(this ILogger logger, string myQuery);
}
```

So that we can log like this:

```cs
internal class MyBeautifulQueryHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyBeautifulQueryHandler> _logger;

    public MyBeautifulQueryHandler(ILogger<MyBeautifulQueryHandler> logger) => _logger = logger;

    public async Task ExecuteAsync(MyBeautifulQuery query)
    {
        _logger.ExecutingQuery(nameof(MyBeautifulQuery));

        // do something asynchronously
    }
}
```

This patterns using the `nameof` operator occurs again and again in our codebase.

I'm wondering whether compile-time logging source generation supports something like this:

```cs
_logger.ExecutingQuery<MyBeautifulQuery>();
```

or even better

```cs
_logger.ExecutingQuery();
```

with both resulting in the same log message `Executing query MyBeautifulQuery`. So I'm looking for something similar to `CallerMemberNameAttribute`.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: There is also *CallerFilePathAttribute* attribute. If you have one class per file, and files always named the same way as the class, this will be sort of equivalent. Even if you might need to strip directories & extension from the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a layer of indirection:

```
public static partial class LoggerExtensions
{
    [LoggerMessage(
        EventId = 1953,
        EventName = "ExecutingQuery",
        Level = LogLevel.Information,
        Message = "Executing query {MyQuery}")]
    static partial void LogExecutingQuery(ILogger logger, string myQuery);

    public static void ExecutingQuery<T>(this ILogger logger)
    {
          LogExecutingQuery(logger, typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

Would have your desired usage:

```
_logger.ExecutingQuery<MyBeautifulQuery>();
```